# number of choices to put k bricks of lengths 3 on n spots

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Consider that you have $k$ bricks of length $1$ and you want to put on a bar of length $n$. In how many ways can you organize them? The answer is simply given by: $$\binom{n}{k}$$
Now, consider that the length of each bricks are equal to $3$, in how many ways can you organize them?

Comment: If you fill from left to right (planning ahead that placing all bricks will be possible) the first brick from the left can be placed from position 1 up to n - 3k + 1, giving n - 3k + 1 placements - then depending where you placed it, the next bricks number of placements can be calculated from the remaining spaces and k-1 left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $k$ bricks will occupy $3k$ of the $n$ spots, leaving $n-3k$ spots unoccupied. In effect you’re lining up $k$ ‘fat spots’ (bricks) and $n-3k$ ordinary spots. That’s a total of $n-2k$ objects, $k$ of which are bricks, and the bricks can be any $k$ of the $n-2k$ objects, so there are $$\binom{n-2k}k$$ possible arrangements.

For example, if $n=10$ and $k=2$ there are $\binom62=15$ possible arrangements, all of which are shown below, with $b$ for *brick* and $s$ for *spot*:

$$\begin{align*}
&bbssss,bsbsss,bssbss,bsssbs,bssssb\\
&sbbsss,sbsbss,sbssbs,sbsssb\\
&ssbbss,ssbsbs,ssbssb\\
&sssbbs,sssbsb\\
&ssssbb
\end{align*}$$

Comment: That's what I found. Thank you.

Comment: @Salsifis: You’re welcome.